# How can I make ng-repeats on nested data produce flat output?

Tags: angularjs

I have some nested data (Python code):

```
groups = [
    ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    ['a', 'b', 'c']
]
```

Which I'm trying to present as a flat list of table rows (Python code):

```
for group_idx, group in enumerate(groups):
    for item_idx, item in enumerate(group):
        print(f'<tr><td> { group_idx }: { item } </td></tr>')
```

This is the output I need:

```
<tr><td> 0: a </td></tr>
<tr><td> 0: b </td></tr>
<tr><td> 0: c </td></tr>
<tr><td> 1: a </td></tr>
<tr><td> 1: b </td></tr>
<tr><td> 1: c </td></tr>
<tr><td> 2: a </td></tr>
<tr><td> 2: b </td></tr>
<tr><td> 2: c </td></tr>
```

I'm sorting and filtering both groups and group items, if it matters.

Answer (score 1):

Please check if this is what you need:

Code:

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  
  $scope.tableData=  [
    ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    ['d', 'e', 'f'],
    ['g', 'h', 'k']
]

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.5.x" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.11/angular.min.js" data-semver="1.5.11"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>
    <table style="border:1px solid black">
      <tr ng-repeat="data in tableData">
        <td ng-repeat="tdata in data" style="border:1px solid black">{{$parent.$index}}:{{tdata}}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: No, that is pretty much the opposite of what I need.

Comment: @alex, do you want to display the tr,td tags that you have shown in your question ? If yes , where? Or you need to send it to backend?

Comment: If that's what you need, it can be done with some logic in your controller, where you hard code the tr,td for each row.

Comment: I've managed to do what I needed by putting ng-repeats on multiple <tbody> tags instead. Apparently you can have any number of them in a single table.